# Stuck with comparing Strings in C

Tags: c, string, file

So im supposed to write a Soundex Converter code and print the lines from a file  if one of its words has the same Soundex code as the input. I successfully wrote a function for the Soundex conversion but im stuck at the comparing part. Sorry if this sounds trivial but when i compare the words line by line, strcmp seems to fail everytime. Here's the code... Sorry if its too long

```
    #include<string.h>
    #include<ctype.h>
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>

    char *soundex(char *s,char* name)
    {
        int si = 1;
        char c;
        //char *s = (char *)malloc(1000);
        //                 ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
        char mappings[] = "01230120022455012623010202";

        s[0] = toupper(name[0]);

        for(int i = 1, l = strlen(name); i < l; i++)
        {
            c = toupper(name[i]) - 65;

            if(c >= 0 && c <= 25)
            {
                if(mappings[c] != '0')
                {
                    if(mappings[c] != s[si-1])
                    {
                        s[si] = mappings[c];
                        si++;
                    }

                    if(si > 3)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if(si <= 3)
        {
            while(si <= 3)
            {
                s[si] = '0';
                si++;
            }
        }

        //printf("%s\n",s);
        return s;

    }

    void search(char line[10000],char str[1000])
    {   
        int i,j=0;
        char test[1000];
        char s[1000];
        char b[1000];
        for(i=0;line[i] != '\0';i++)
        {   
            if(line[i] == ' ')
            continue;

            test[j] = line[i];
            j++;
            if(line[i+1] == ' ' || line[i+1] == '\0')
            {
                //soundex(test);
                test[j] = '\0';

                if(strcmp(soundex(s,test),soundex(b,str)) == 0);
                {
                    printf("%s\n",soundex(s,test));
                    printf("%s\n",soundex(b,str));
                    printf("%s",line);
                    break;
                }
                j = 0;
                memset(test,0,strlen(test));
            }

        }
    }

    int main()
    {

        char a[1000],f[1000];
        char s[1000];
        gets(a);
        //soundex(s,a);
        //printf("%s",s);

        scanf("%s",f);
        FILE *fp=fopen(f,"r");
        if(fp==NULL)
        {
            printf("File doesnot exist bro");
        }
        else
        {
            long long linenum=1;
            char line[10000];
            while(fgets(line,10000,fp)!=NULL) //Or fscanf
            {
                search(line,a);
                //printf("%s",line);
                linenum++;
            }
        }

        fclose(fp);
     }
```

The Problem is arising with the strcmp command in the Search function as it prints the lines even after the results differ. I even print the results of the comparison afterwards to be sure. Any leads would be aprreciated. Again sorry for the long code.

Comment: this is a problem that needs to be solved with debugging first. Try to debug it and then come back if you are stuck.

Comment: and try and create a [MCVE] next time

Comment: also this code is crawling with compiler warnings, fix those first. ` test[j] == '\0';` for 1

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the `;` off. **Don't ignore compiler warnings!**

```
prog.c:70:17: warning: this ‘if’ clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]
                     if(strcmp(soundex(s,test),soundex(b,str)) == 0);


if(strcmp(soundex(s,test),soundex(b,str)) == 0)
```

also

```
prog.c: In function ‘search’:
prog.c:68:25: warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]
                 test[j] == '\0';
```

and

```
prog.c: In function ‘main’:
prog.c:89:9: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘gets’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
         gets(a);
```

Comment: Wow, literally spent 30 min for that. Thank you and it didnt show up as a complier warning on Dev C++

Comment: try cranking up the warning levels (or use a better compiler)

Comment: @Reddy90 : Dev-C++ is not a compiler it is an IDE, and the warning shown will only be given with the warning options specified in the answer - though possibly not even then in the GCC version shipped with Dev-C++.  Even then the problem could be solved with better coding style and a debugger - not calling the function in the `if` and inspecting its return value in the debugger for example - you would then see that `strcmp()` worked, and the problem was with the if.

Comment: You should be using **Orwell Dev-C++** and not the (obsolete) older version. http://orwelldevcpp.blogspot.com/